# Android, How can I get text from TextView in OnClick

Tags: java, android, onclick, textview

I have some `TextView` and each have an `OnClickListener`. I would like get information in this method to `TextView`

```
TextView tv2 = new TextView(this,(String)book.get(i),this);
tv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Contact.this,Discution.class);
        //String str = this.getText(); //like this
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

How can I do : `this.getText();` in an `OnClickListener` ?

Comment: Make tv2 to final and access it's value in onClick() like tv2.getText().toString();

Comment: `TextView tv2 = new TextView(this,(String)book.get(i),this);` is wrong. there is no such constructor for textview

Comment: do you have a lsitvie with textviews. Need more info. But what you are doing is wrong

Comment: Do you have custom class by the name TextView??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Contact.this,Discution.class);

            String str = tv2.getText().toString(); 

            startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: the textview constructor does not match the ones in the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: i don't understand how come this works and is accepted??

Comment: my focus on was how to get text from textview not in that line.

Comment: but that is totally wrong. It should not run at all should throw a run time exception. Wrong suggestion.

Comment: yeah tell him to change that line.

Comment: i did comment on his post but i never gotta a reply any way i suggested that in my post and that is why i am surprised this got accepted

Answer (score 10):

This is wrong

```
TextView tv2 = new TextView(this,(String)book.get(i),this);
```

You will need TextView to be final and the constructor should match any of the below

```
TextView(Context context)
TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
```

It should be

```
final TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
```

You are not using any of the above. Totally wrong

Then inside onClick

```
String str = tv2.getText().toString();
```

Its declared final cause you access tv2 inside annonymous inner class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing

You can also use the `View v`.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) v;
String str = tv.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use: `tv2` in place of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`tv2.getText().toString;`

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have this in your layout:

```
<TextView android:id           ="@+id/myText"
          android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize     ="26dp"
          android:text         ="bla bla bla..."
          android:textColor    ="#0000ff"
          android:clickable    ="true"
          android:onClick      ="onMyClick"/>
```

Now lets get the text content from ***myText*** element when it gets clicked

```
public void onMyClick(View v)
     {
     TextView t=(TextView)v;
     String s=t.getText().toString();
     //do whatever you want with the string s
     }
```

> Note the boolean ***android:clickable="true"*** on the layout element [ *it's mandatory* ]